# How to put comma in counted numbers?

Tags: php, mysql, count

hey huys im counting my table with this code:

```
$county = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) from table where type = 'application'");
$county = mysql_result($county, 0);
$applications = ''.$county.'';
```

this give me result like 1156563. but I want to see it like 1,156,563 with commas. how can i do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) should be what you need

> If only one parameter is given, number
>   will be formatted without decimals,
>   but with a comma (",") between every
>   group of thousands.

```
<?php
echo number_format(23124154);

//output: 23,124,154
```